# react and express: get image from public folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm serving 2 different react apps through 1 nodejs backend. Nodejs code (simplified):

```
const api = require('./api/routes');
app.use('/api', api);

const admin = require('./admin/routes');
app.use('/api/admin', admin);

app.use('/admin', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/react/admin-client/build/')));
app.get('/admin/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/react/admin-client/build/index.html'))
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/react/client/build/')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/react/client/build/index.html'))
});
```

When I navigate to localhost:5000/admin (admin-client app), I see the admin client and everything works just fine. But when I navigate to localhost:5000 (client-app), I see the app, but the assets in the public folder aren't found.

When console.logging process.env.PUBLIC_URL in the admin-client, I get `/admin`. When I console.log the same thing in the client, I get a blank response.

I'm using an apache vhost to proxy requests from localhost(:80) to localhost:5000.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ProxyPass "/" http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

When visiting http://localhost/admin/logo.png, I get the logo of the admin-client react app which is in the public-folder.

When visiting http://localhost/logo.png, I **don't** get the logo of the client react app in which is in the public folder, instead, it's treated like it's a page (a '/' is appended to the url).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My server is at directory like /appDirectory/config/expressSetup.ts

```
 public app: express.Application;

constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.appClient = express();
    this.config();
    this.routes();
    if (!IS_DEV_MODE) {
        this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../../client/build')));
        this.app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../../client/build', 'index.html'));
        });
    }
    this.errorHandler();
}
```

And my client is at /appDirectory/client/build. Make sure you folder which contains icon of files placed inside build folder.